Swiftui put a green border around QR code
I used this tutorial to create a QR code scanner Building a QR Code Scanner App in SwiftUI
Unfortunately this tutorial does not tell me how to put a box around the QR code.  With some modifications I got a CGRect of the QRCode positions and I'm trying to create a box in the view.
    @State var scanResult = "No QR code detected"
    @State var barcodeBounds : CGRect?
    
    @Binding var navPath : NavigationPath

        var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ScannerRepresentable(result: $scanResult, barcodeBounds: $barcodeBounds)
                                    
                Path(barcodeBounds!)
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .border(.green)
           
                Text(scanResult)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.bottom)
            }  
        }
}

I tried with both path and rectangle.  I can put a filled in shape over the QR code, but if I try putting a border around it, the boarder goes around the entire view. Screenshot below

As you can see the green border is around the whole screen instead of the QR code.  How do I fix this?

Answering my own question.  Let me know if you have a better solution.
I was able to solve this problem by using a shape instead of a path.
First create the shape
struct Box : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        
        return path
    }
}

Then in the view
Box()
    .path(in: barcodeBounds!)
    .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))

